# Is it possible to specify forbidden values on a slug field?

Tags: symfony, slug

I have an entity which have a `slug` field defined and managed using Gedmo Slug library.

Is it possible to easily define a list of unwanted values for this field (e.G. `'edit'`, `'new'`, `'delete'`...) or do I need to make something all by myself?

Comment: Using Doctrine's events you could check the forbidden values in a method 'preInsert' for example. So a 'BaseEntity' has a constant array with `['new', 'edit', 'delete']` and the 'preInsert' method in every child entity checks if the slug that would be generated equals one of these forbidden values.

Comment: Have you try to use the regex validator on your field and black list your words? [regex validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)

Comment: Using Doctrine events is a bad idea and a bad practice, they are not here to 
 validate datas from a form! Validation is different, you can use 2 different constraints, one for slug(gedmo) and one to blacklist words(regex).

Comment: My problem is not really about data coming from a form. For example, a user can create a blog article with the title Edit. I just don't want Slug to automatically save for the `slug` of the blog post a string equal to `edit`, but instead for example save `edit_1`. I was wondering if this use case was planned in the Slug library, it seems not. I'll try the propositions that as been told when I will have time for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SlugHandler I guess.

Take a look at this : http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/sluggable.html#slug-handlers

You could create your own `SlugHandler`, add some `SlugHandlerOption` with your forbidden words, and use a simple regex to check if the generated slug is valid.

If not, you could modify the generated slug or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand your request. It lacks a bit of clarity.

In my opinion, the Gedmo librairy can not do this easily.

In your place, I will create a value that I will work according to your imperatives and I will let the annotation slug work with this value.